# Creating a Dictionary with a list of values by appending in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with a list of values.

```
mydict = {
a = []
b = []
}
```

I want to append values of key a. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydict = {}
mydict['a'] = []
mydict['a'].append("enter value here")
```

let you have a list and assing to a

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]
mydict['a'] = l
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Create the dictionary, then access the `list` and append to it.

```
>>> mydict = {'a':[], 'b':[]}
>>> mydict['a'].append(3)
>>> mydict
{'a': [3], 'b': []}
```